# Heroku custom exception page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, heroku

is it possible - and in this case how - to have a custom html page when an exception happens on production environment in Heroku?

Right now there is a centered white box with red text:

"We're sorry, but something went wrong.

We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly."

Thanks,
Augusto

Answer (score 2):

Custom error page is possible in heroku , as far as I know there is a heroku plugin/add-on for it

Check this link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-pages